# Error while creating a new "OpportunityLineItemSchedule" using SFDC Partner API

Tags: java, salesforce

When I try to create a new OpportunityLineItemSchedule I'm running into following error..

Error code: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY

Error message: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id

Attached is the code snippet. Any help will be extremely useful.

```
SObject[] rs = new SObject[1];
MessageElement[] specificRS = new MessageElement[6];
specificRS[0] = new MessageElement(new QName("OpportunityLineItemId"),"00k7000000DFLqfAAH");
specificRS[1] = new MessageElement(new QName("Description"),"Rev Schedule Descr");
specificRS[2] = new MessageElement(new QName("Type"),"Quantity"); 
specificRS[3] = new MessageElement(new QName("Quantity"),(double)2);
specificRS[4] = new MessageElement(new QName("Revenue"),(double)400000.00);
specificRS[5] = new MessageElement(new QName("ScheduleDate"),"2010-10-30");

rs[0] = new SObject();
rs[0].setType("OpportunityLineItemSchedule");
rs[0].set_any(specificRS);

SaveResult[] sr = null;
try {
  sr = binding.create(rs);
} catch (Exception ex) {
  System.out.println("An unexpected error has occurred." + ex.getMessage());
  ex.printStackTrace();
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following works..

```
    MessageElement[] specificRS2 = new MessageElement[5];
specificRS2[0] = new MessageElement(new QName("OpportunityLineItemId"),"00k7000000DFcOG");
// PricebookEntryId can be found by joining PricebookEntry and Pricebook2 tables (on Product2Id and 
specificRS2[1] = new MessageElement(new QName("Description"),"Rev Schedule Descr2");
specificRS2[2] = new MessageElement(new QName("ScheduleDate"),"2010-10-31");
//specificRS[3] = new MessageElement(new QName("Quantity"),(double)2);
specificRS2[3] = new MessageElement(new QName("Revenue"),(double)10.00);
//specificRS[4] = new MessageElement(new QName("Type"),"Quantity"); // and/or "Revenue"
specificRS2[4] = new MessageElement(new QName("Type"),"Revenue"); // and/or "Quantity"

rs[1] = new SObject();
rs[1].setType("OpportunityLineItemSchedule");
rs[1].set_any(specificRS2);

SaveResult[] sr = null;
try {
  sr = binding.create(rs);
} catch (Exception ex) {
  System.out.println("An unexpected error has occurred." + ex.getMessage());
  ex.printStackTrace();
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is usually an error when code is trying to use an ID for an object that doesn't exist, or that the user doesn't have access to. I take it the only difference between the 2 snippets is the OpportunityLineItem ID? Check that the user running the code can access the item with that ID.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Allowed Type Field Values](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitemschedule.htm#i1457635) and [Allowed Quantity and Revenue Field Values](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitemschedule.htm#i1457710) documentation for OpportunityLineItemSchedule.

> The allowed Type values for an OpportunityLineItemSchedule depend on the product-level schedule preferences and whether the line item has any existing schedules

You may need to check if there are existing OpportunityLineItemSchedule records.

> The allowable Quantity and Revenue field values depend on the value of the Type field

You only set the Quantity or Revenue field, not both.